# How to tell a GridViewRow to perform as a SEO-friendly link?

Tags: c#, asp.net, seo

I have a GridView that has multiple columns. Let's say I have a business modell that looks like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
 public String Title {get;set;}
 public DateTime Date {get;set;}
 public String NavigateUrl {get;set;}
}
```

My grid has two visible columns (Title and Date).
 What I want to do, is to make each row clickable and to act like a link, that is going to the specified NavigateUrl. 
No problem so far.

I could use the OnRowDataBound-Event to assign a Javascript that tells the Grid that I performed a Select and in the OnRowEvent, I could perform a Response.Redirect.
But that is **not** what I want to do, because it is not SEO friendly.

How can I make the whole "grid row as link" idea SEO friendly?

**Edit**: Adding an extra, visible column is no option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a link as a column in the grid, and make the tr's onclick event fire off the link.

Comment: Not a real option. I can't add an extra column only containing the link. There musn't be any visible representation of the hyperlink in the grid, except for the changing of the mouse cursor.

Comment: Ok, your answer might be an solution. How can I fire off the link with the tr's on click event?

Comment: `<tr onclick="javascript:window.location=document.getElementById('myLinkId').href;" ...>`

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to make the GridView's cell contents LinkButtons, with the NavigateUrl specified. They will then show up as ordinary links on the page. You can define this behavior in the ASPX/ASCX markup and then DataBind, or dynamically build your GridView by adding rows manually in a loop through your data objects, setting the properties manually. Either one will work; I daresay databinding may be a bit faster but it can also be fiddly.

Comment: This isn't adding a column; this is changing one or both of the existing columns' contents to be a link instead of ordinary text, with the NavigateUrl of that link set to the link from your data. If you change the columns from ordinary BoundFields to HyperlinkFields or TemplateFields, you can set a URI to navigate to, which shows up as a vanilla "a href" in the client's HTML. You can use CSS or inline styles to make them still look like text to the user if you like.